# Encountering parse base error (SAS)

Tags: sas

I've been stuck on this the whole day and I hope to get some help from the community. I am still learning SAS so this might be a beginner's question. Please bear with me.

Here I have a code that I am currently working on. I'm running this using eclipse dataserver plugins:

```
libname myInput 'D:\_TD5910372542151565380';

proc datasets lib=myInput;
run; 

quit;

ods csv files="D:/_TD5910372542151565380/myTest.csv";

proc print data=myInput.inputContainer;
     title "Random";
run;

ods csv close;
```

I am trying to print the content in the inputContainer into a CSV file. Here is the console log that I am getting:

```
[MPRINT] Parsing Base DataServer
/* 0001 */  libname myInput 'D:\_TD5910372542151565380';


NOTE: Library myinput assigned successfully
[MPRINT] Parsing Base DataServer
/* 0002 */  proc datasets lib=myInput;
/* 0003 */  run;

-------------------- 10:34: PROC DATASETS --------------------
NOTE: Time taken: 000:00:00.000
[MPRINT] Parsing Base DataServer
/* 0002 */  quit;

[MPRINT] Parsing Base DataServer
/* 0003 */  ods csv files="D:/_TD5910372542151565380/myTest.csv";
/* 0004 */  proc print data=myInput.inputContainer;
/* 0005 */  title "Random";
/* 0006 */  run;

ERROR: Parsing exception - aborting
ERROR: DS-00274 : Could not parse base DataServer code: Encountered " <ALPHANUM> "ods "" at line 3, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    ";" ...
    "*" ...
    "data" ...
    "proc" ...
    (and 9 more)
```

I checked the lines a lot of time but I am still not sure if I am missing something. I also browsed a lot of websites to find what can fix this error. Hopefully a second pair of eye can point out what exactly has gone wrong.

Thank you in advance. XD

Comment: How did you generate that log?  It looks like whatever tool that did that did not recognize ODS as a valid statement. Did you run the code directly with SAS or are you using some other kind of front end interface?

Comment: I am using Dataserver eclipse plugin. When I run it, it will output the log into Eclipse output console. I couldn't get the ods running with the plugin so I had to resort to exporting the file instead.

Comment: Sounds like the plug-in doesn't undertand newer SAS syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Haha... I found the solution myself.The way I solved this is as following:

```
libname myInput 'D:\_TD5910372542151565380';
proc datasets lib=myInput;
run; 

data something;
    set myInput.inputContainer; 
run;

proc export data=something
    outfile="D:/Example.csv"
    dbms=csv
    replace;
run;
```

It seems that you have to set the data first to take the obs file. Then, there are no separated semi colons until replace; Which I did wrong in the above. Hope this help anyone out there.